# Set UIView to correct device width with Auto Layout when using Universal Storyboard: trailing and leading spaces give wrong value

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, autolayout

When using Auto Layout and Universal Storyboard, we discovered that using Trailing Space and Leading Space to make a UIView's width equal to the device width does not work.

While the UIView looks fine on the Storyboard, the UIView's width comes back as 600, even though the device is an iPhone 5s and should be 320. According to other SO posts and documentation online, the Universal Storyboard has dimensions of 600x600.

What's the right way to make the UIView share the same width as the device using Auto Layout and Universal Storyboard while also making sure its frame has the same value?

Comment: Could you provide screenshot with IB constraints you made?

Comment: check this links..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560814/ios-iphone-6-autolayout-full-width-and-height/30566105#30566105    and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495323/uicollectionview-is-too-wide-how-can-i-make-it-the-width-of-the-device/30497767#30497767

Answer (score 0):

Add equal width and equal height with main view and add leading and top with main view with Zero constant value.